# How to connect to 802.1x EAP wireless network with (debian wheezy)?

Tags: networking, wifi, debian

I able to connect to a 802.1x EAP wireless network with my android phone. Now I would like to connect with this network with my Raspberry pi with this module Edimax EW-7811Un.

Here is the network details (read from my phone):
Security: 802.1x EAP
EAP Method: PEAP
Phase 2 authentication: None
CA certification: (unspecified)
Identity: 'myname'
Password: 'mypassword'
Proxy: None

Now Here is /etc/network/interfaces file from my Raspberry Pi. I'm not sure this is good:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

And here is /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf file from my Raspberry Pi.
I am not sure this file is configured well

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
    network={
            ssid="NETWORK8021x"
            proto=RSN
            key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
            pairwise=CCMP TKIP
            group=CCMP TKIP
            eap=TLS
            identity="myname"
            ca_cert="/etc/cert/ca.pem"
            client_cert="/etc/cert/user.pem"
            private_key="/etc/cert/user.prv"
            private_key_passwd="mypassword"
            priority=1
    }
```

This code is from this site:
http://www.lsi.upc.edu/lclsi/Manuales/wireless/files/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
after that:
sudo ifdown wlan0
sudo ifup wlan0

iwconfig
```

I got this:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"myessid"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: F8:4F:57:30:88:F2   
          Bit Rate:72.2 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=66/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

After that:

```
    sudo /sbin/wpa_supplicant -P /var/run/wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid -i wlan0 -D nl80211,wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

I get this error:
nl80211: 'nl80211' generic netlink not found
Failed to initialize driver 'nl80211'
rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=0
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
wlan0: Trying to associate with f8:4f:57:30:88:f2 (SSID='myssid' freq=2412 MHz)
wlan0: Association request to the driver failed
wlan0: Associated with 00:00:00:00:00:00
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=f8:4f:57:30:88:f2 reason=0
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=0
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=0
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
wlan0: Trying to associate with f8:4f:57:30:88:f2 (SSID='myssid' freq=2412 MHz)
wlan0: Association request to the driver failed
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, the easiest way to do this if you connect from Desktop after that automatically generate the wpa_supplicant.conf file, and thats just works fine.

Comment: How did you generate the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file from the desktop?